# In which state is MyBatis' (iBatis) Abator? Is there any other tool?

Tags: java, ibatis, mybatis

I stumbled accross Abator @ http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/tools/abator/ by chance, which promises to be a code generator for myBatis (iBatis) mapping files. Looks promising, but I cannot find any information about the state of the project or any download link.

Does anybody know, if Abator is still actively developed? Is there a successor?

Comment: wow, Abator.. I almost forgot if it exists.

Comment: So, do you have any experience using it? The whole thing looks rather dead to me, to be honest ;(

Comment: I did experiment with it like 2 years backs. Then our team preferred writing everything by hand. And since it wasn't hard to do so and learning curve was small, we actually never touched it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mybatis Generator tool is available and it generates code/artifacts for both ibatis2 and ibatis3(Mybatis)

Its can be downloaded from [here](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/Generator)

Comment: Like Nishant, "Then our team preferred writing everything by hand..."  The generator is great for getting started but once you learn the syntax, the generator makes for very ugly code.